# Valid answer deleted on Communist question

Tags: support, moderation, specific-answer

This answer in the [Communist question:Acts 2:44,45; Acts 4:32, Does Acts say that Christianity teaches a form of Communism?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/46860/acts-244-45-acts-432-does-acts-say-that-christianity-teaches-a-form-of-commu) seems the only accurate in the topic, but was deleted by Steve.

> The main distinguishing characteristic of Acts is that the "communism' is fully voluntary, which distinguishes it from all its other historical manifestations
>
> in Communism of today, the State is also the Religion in actuality if not in effect See the recently opened DC Museum of Communism and the works of Michael Burleigh

Not that communists should be banned or discriminated against, but the answer doesn't need any proof links, although there maybe expert users who can edit and provide some sources for the fact that communism is indeed confused with altruism among naive people. There are worse answers allowed un deleted here. This answer provides good source to learn about communism or socialism from some museum.

Socialism is not altruism. Socialism was invented in 19th century. Marx published "The Communist Manifesto" in 1848, which became the principal statement of European socialist and communist ideology. It was a result on industrial revolution and labour union, and flawed economics.

Free trade or business is defined by capitalism. Thus, socialism as an economic policy didn't exist prior to 19th century Europe. The Bible assumes a capitalist free worldview and doesn't teach that the state should force uniformity in destribution of wealth but that each deserves according to his merit, people should charitably provide to the poor. Forced distribution of wealth in uniformity means making all equally poor and blocking talents and uniqueness of individuals. It promotes the Spirit of envy, hatred, robbery as seen in the socialist organizations and elite global sinister organizations.

Steve has revealed his communist bias in previous question which presupposed socialism [Does Capitalism shape modern translations of the Ten Minas?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/does-capitalism-shape-modern-translations-of-the-ten-minas).

Some other moderator needs to edit and improve that deleted answer, perhaps just cite some basic Wikipedia or dailywire articles which debunks the myth of socialism as people confuses it with altruism.

Comment: Not only is SE-BH the wrong site to discuss theology and to argue for one or other theology ; it is also the wrong site to discuss politics and to argue for one or other political faction.

Comment: It's just a low quality answer, Michael. Unfortunately the user is no longer around to improve it, so rather than just raising an improvement notice I opted to delete. If it's any help, I don't have any firm political commitments in any particular direction - I'd as readily vote red or blue in my country depending on what policies were on the ballot. I welcome your scrutiny on this answer - your reaction to this has puzzled me though. Do you have strong commitments on this topic yourself?

Comment: The OP's last paragraph doesn't even sound like a fully formed thought or sentence, so doesn't read as entirely coherent, either. Usually you're really supportive of removing VLQ content, so I'm interested in what you see as different here.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146177/discussion-on-question-by-michael16-valid-answer-deleted-on-communist-question); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "*I'd as readily vote red or blue in my country*" — note that in the rest of the world (and until recently in the USA), red and blue have the exact opposite meaning of how Americans use it today. Red is liberal, socialist, communist, etc. and Blue is conservative, free-enterprise, capitalist, etc., but, a few elections back, the American colours traded places and have been a source of confusion to the rest of us ever since.  (Are "Red Chinese" now those in Taiwan? Are "Commie Pinkos" now leftists that are tempted by capitalism? Does "Red Square" in Moscow celebrate the rejection of communism?)

Answer (score 0):

> This answer in the Communist question:Acts 2:44,45; Acts 4:32, Does Acts say that Christianity teaches a form of Communism? seems the only accurate in the topic, but was deleted by Steve.

I can read only the excerpt you reproduce here because on BH my rep score is too low. That excerpt reflects that the deleted answer is essentially conclusory and very lacking in articulation. My impression is that deletion stemmed from author's sloppiness, not from moderator Steve's bias for or against an economic model. Disclaimer: If it matters --although it mostly should not-- I am an atheist, Nietzschean, and a strong supporter of neoliberal economics.

Extrapolating or forcing an ancient text to implications on modern paradigms entails a high risk of anachronism. The matter at issue requires a thorough understanding of complexities that extend far beyond two bare citations of Acts. These complexities relate much more to Christianity and Economics than to Biblical Hermeneutics, and this fact is palpable also in the points you develop in this post.

On top of that, the author [of the answer] dug a bigger hole by lightheartedly alluding to "*all [Communism's] other historical manifestations*" without elaborating on, and without pointing to evidence of, the historicist contrast he suggests. Case in point: It would not surprise me that also textbooks in North Korea purport that communism there is "fully voluntary". But why would people from a subsequent civilization take at face value that official narrative? The author here may believe that Acts provides a reliable portrayal of an actual (i.e., historical) economic organization from back then, but his sole belief adds no hermeneutical support to his assertion.

The second statement in that answer is also hard to defend. For starters, the language "*in actuality if not in effect*" makes no sense, since in this context "actuality" and "effect" mean the same. More important is the author's failure to articulate how the opening of a museum about Communism implies that "*the State is also the Religion*", let alone in a way that is relevant to hermeneutics of the Bible. Governments and power groups usually resort to a repertoire of tactics and elements that are of a religious nature, but each topic warrants actually giving specifics of the context at issue.

Lastly, I shamefully admit that I had never heard of Michael Burleigh, but the author still ought to develop the relation he believes "*the works of Michael Burleigh*" have with the hermeneutical question as posted. Even someone knowledgeable about Mr. Burleigh's profile would have to admit that the author's mention is too poor and does not substantiate a position.

Comment: I quoted the whole answer of that post. The objection is that there are worse quality of writings allowed here, so deletion of that one raised flag as discrimination. Regardless of how vague and inarticulate it was, the short mention of that stated communism shouldn't be confused with altruism is the perfect answer for the question. Which I elaborated in my answer. I think it's a common tactic to treat socialism as very subjective to avoid a concrete conception which evades any attempt to discuss and critique it.

Comment: @Michael16 "*there are worse quality of writings allowed here*". For sure, but did those contributors delete their account soon after barely posting some VLQ answer? "*I elaborated in my answer.*" That is exactly the difference with the sloppy answer that got deleted. And, although I agree with most of the points in your well written answer (*cf.* I dispute the generalizations about atheists), even there the hermeneutical content is rather scarce. The fact that, despite said scarcity, your answer remains undeleted tends to disprove the ideological discrimination you allege.